# Is an 'or' in the query faster for Active Record lookups if you need to further filter it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Which is a faster query? In the first example I make 2 calls to DB.

In the second example I make 1 call to DB but then I need to further refine that data to get my total.

```
made  = SingleBet.where(maker_id: @current_user.id, taker_id: user.id, status: 'accepted')

taken = SingleBet.where(taker_id: @current_user.id, maker_id: user.id, status: 'accepted')

@total = made.pluck(:amount).sum + taken.pluck(:taker_amount).sum
```

vs

```
made_and_taken = SingleBet.where(maker_id: @current_user.id, taker_id: user.id, status: 'accepted').or(SingleBet.where(taker_id: @current_user.id, maker_id: user.id, status: 'accepted'))

@total = made_and_taken.where(maker_id: @current_user.id).pluck(:amount).sum + made_and_taken.where(taker_id: @current_user.id).pluck(:taker_amount).sum
```

You notice that in the second example I need to use a `where` clause when calculating the @total. I am thinking this second example is faster because the 'where' clause is not going to the DB?

Thank you!

Comment: You can do this in one query. Are you comfortable using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` or `find_by_sql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You make 2 DB queries in both cases, only the second approach is ugly and doesn't make any sense. You should check in the console what SQL queries are sent and understand what is going on.

2) Change `relation.pluck(:amount).sum` to `relation.sum(:amount)`. It will be much faster.

3) The first approach looks fine, however you can perform that calculation with 1 DB call, but that will require writing some raw SQL. And the solution might depend on the kind of DB you are using (MySQL? PostgreSQL? etc.).

The result SQL will look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(
  CASE 
    WHEN maker_id = {{@current_user.id}} THEN amount
    ELSE taker_amount
  END
)
FROM single_bets
WHERE status = 'accepted' AND (maker_id = {{@current_user.id}} OR taker_id = {{user.id}});
```

Comment: Postgres on Heroku is the DB. I will look to make this with 1 raw query. Thank you!